# Split a pandas dataframe using unique; Render as separate tables in Jinja2

Tags: python, pandas, jinja2

I'm working on a project wherein I load a .csv file into a pandas dataframe and make a .PDF report, using Python 3.6 + pandas + jinja2 + weasyprint.

csv -> pandas -> jinja2 -> weasyprint

**Here's my challenge:**
One of pandas dataframes contains info that I want to split by the unique entries in one of its columns, and then display separate tables in jinja2 for each of those splits.

Sample dataframe:

```
         Clothing  Color   Size
    0    Shirt     Blue    M
    1    Shirt     Blue    L
    2    Shirt     Black   L
    3    Pants     Black   L
    4    Pants     Blue    XL
    5    Jacket    Blue    L
    6    Jacket    Brown   L
```

I can successfully send this single Pandas dataframe to jinja2 as a whole, by assigning df.to_html() to jinja2 template_vars.

```
template_vars = {"title" : "My Title",
                 "df": df.to_html()
                 }
```

and then in the template.html file, calling on that by stating:

```
<div class="table_standard campaign_kpis_table">
 {{ campaign_kpis }}
</div>
```

Now, I want to be able to take the Pandas dataframe, and split it out into several dataframes based on the unique items in one column. In this example, 'Color'.

I can do that by using:

`df_splits = (df['Color'].unique())`

Then, knowing all the unique entries, I can iterate over them, and get the separate dataframe "splits". Please tell me if there's a better word than 'split' to use here, and I'll edit. :)

So I can easily print those separate splits in the terminal by doing something like:

```
for df_split in df_splits:
    df_split = df.loc[df['Color']==df_split]
    print (df_split)
```

But how do send those off to jinja2 to be displayed as separate tables?

For my purposes, there could be anywhere from only 1 to as many as 10 unique Colors in the original dataframe. The amount of unique entries will always change, depending on what's in stock. As I understand it, this will create 1 to 10 separate dataframe splits.

What do I write so that jinja2 creates tables for each of these dataframe splits?

Please let me know if you need more code, or if I've failed to adequately explain my situation.

The full code for the " -> jinja2 -> weasyprint" section is based off of https://pbpython.com/pdf-reports.html.

It currently looks like this:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))

template = env.get_template("templates/template.html")

template_vars = {"df": df.to_html(),
             }

html_out = template.render(template_vars)

with open("/path/to/report.html", "w") as fh:
fh.write(html_out)

from weasyprint import HTML
HTML(string=html_out).write_pdf("/path/to/report.pdf", stylesheets=["templates/style.css"])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of unique() you are looking for pandas groupby().  [Here is the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).
here are the steps:

You can create a groupby object using `gb = df.groupby('Color')` 
You can think of the object looking like this:

---

```
[('Black',   <black_dataframe>)
('Blue',   <blue_dataframe>)
('Brown',   <brown_dataframe>)]
```

#### the enclosing structure is not really a list but just acts like one. it's iterable.

---

make a template called mytemplate.html in the same folder as the code to run it (for now).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
   {% for results in data.values() %}
        {{ results | safe}}
    {% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

You would send it off with:

```
from jinja2 import Environment, FileSystemLoader 
import webbrowser as wb 
from pathlib import Path
import io
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO('Shirt,Blue,M\nShirt,Blue,L\nShirt,Black,L\nPants,Black,L\nPants,Blue,XL\nJacket,Blue,L\nJacket,Brown,L\n'), names=['Clothing', 'Color', 'Size'])
gb = df.groupby('Color')
env = Environment(loader=FileSystemLoader('.'))
template = env.get_template("mytemplate.html") 
data = {x:y.to_html() for x,y in gb} 
template_vars = {'title': "Tables, Tables everywhere", 'data' : data} 
html_out = template.render(template_vars)  
Path('myoutfile.html').write_text(html_out) 
wb.open(f"""file://{Path('.').absolute()}/myoutfile.html""")
```

Comment: Wow. Amazing detail. Thank you!! 

Groupby is definitely the better first step, isn't it? 

I'm sorry that I failed to supply the code I'm currently using for the last two steps:
-> jinja2 -> weasyprint

I'm going to add that code in now, which is based off of the article at https://pbpython.com/pdf-reports.html. Could you guide me on how to use the second method you suggested. I've already named the template file, but don't know where to add the 'data =' section. Apologies!! Thank you already for the clues.

Comment: Originally I was going to say use flask but I'm looking at the tutorial and that FileSystemLoader looks like a better way than having to launch a webservice.  I'll put up new instructions in a moment.

Comment: Original post is edited.  The webbrowser stuff should open if you have linux or mac.  If you have windows I'm not sure how it's interpreted but you can leave off the last 2 lines and just take a look at html_out.

Comment: Many, many thanks for your generous and thoughtful help!! This is working beautifully now. 

The .html file is rendering with '\n' entries above the table - one for every line in the dataframe. But I'm sure I can figure that out on my own. 
Thank you again!!

Comment: For my needs, I just added the following line (though I know it doesn't address the root of the problem): data = str(data).replace('\\n','')

Answer (score 0):

Pass the dataframe and df_splits directly to jinja2 and then use a for loop in jinja2

```
import pandas as pd
from jinja2 import Environment

df = pd.DataFrame([('Shirt','Blue','M'), ('Shirt','Blue','L'), ('Shirt','Black','L'), ('Pants','Black','L'), ('Pants','Blue','XL'), ('Jacket','Blue','L'), ('Jacket','Brown','L')], columns=['Clothing', 'Color', 'Size'])

env = Environment()
tmpl = env.from_string( '''
{% for df_split in df_splits %}
<div>
{{df.loc[df['Color'] == df_split].to_html()}}
</div>
{% endfor %}''')

print(tmpl.render(df=df,df_splits = df['Color'].unique()))
```