# Use GroupBy and Render Pandas Dataframe as Separate HTML files using Jinja2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, jinja2

With help from: [Split a pandas dataframe using unique; Render as separate tables in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58071189/split-a-pandas-dataframe-using-unique-render-as-separate-tables-in-jinja2)

Ultimately, my goal is to take a Pandas dataframe, group it by a column, and render each group within the column as a new HTML file, with the intention to convert it to a PDF file, eventually.

Using the example data in the linked question:

```
     Clothing  Color   Size
0    Shirt     Blue    M
1    Shirt     Blue    L
2    Shirt     Black   L
3    Pants     Black   L
4    Pants     Blue    XL
5    Jacket    Blue    L
6    Jacket    Brown   L
```

If, instead of one html file with separate tables for each item in `Clothing`, I wanted to create multiple html files -- each containing one table for one color: how might I do that?

This code successfully renders my dataframe based on the group I have selected, in this case the unique values of `Color`, as a single HTML file with multiple tables.

I need the code to scale, meaning no hard-coding the unique values of `df['Color']` in advance.

```
import pandas as pd
from jinja2 import Environment

df = pd.DataFrame([('Shirt','Blue','M'), ('Shirt','Blue','L'), ('Shirt','Black','L'), ('Pants','Black','L'), ('Pants','Blue','XL'), ('Jacket','Blue','L'), ('Jacket','Brown','L')], columns=['Clothing', 'Color', 'Size'])

env = Environment()
tmpl = env.from_string( '''
{% for df_split in df_splits %}
<div>
{{df.loc[df['Color'] == df_split].to_html()}}
</div>
{% endfor %}''')

print(tmpl.render(df=df,df_splits = df['Color'].unique()))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create files inside loop using `groupby()`. Here is an example:

```
tmpl = env.from_string("""
    <div>
    {{ df.to_html(index=False) }}
    </div>
""")

for color_name, group_df in df.groupby(['Color']):
    content = tmpl.render(df=group_df)
    file_path = '/tmp/{f_name}.html'.format(f_name=color_name)
    with open(file_path, 'w+') as file:
        print('writing to file {f}'.format(f=file_path))
        # print(content)  # check content before write if you need
        file.write(content)

    # check content after write if you need
    # with open(file_path) as file:
    #     print('reading file {f}. content:'.format(f=file_path))
    #     print(file.read())
```